# SELECT em tabela auto-relacional

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, select

Tenho uma tabela `funcionario`, com atributos: `ID`(PK) e `IDCHEFE` (FK da própria tabela).

Cada funcionário(a) tem um `idchefe` que referencia um outro funcionário (que é chefe dele(a)).

Como fazer um `SELECT` que retorne o nome do funcionario e o nome do seu chefe?

Comment: Sempre poste seu código/estrutura relacionado à pergunta. Facilita bastante para quem for lhe ajudar! [Central de ajuda > Perguntando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como não foi postado a estrutura da sua tabela `funcionario`, vou sugerir a seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE `funcionario`(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `chefeId` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Vou adicionar alguns registros para testar a *query*:

```
INSERT INTO `funcionario` (`nome`, `chefeId`) VALUES
    ('Joaquim', 4),
    ('João', 1),
    ('José', 1),
    ('Jurandir', 5),
    ('Josefina', 2);
```

Agora sim posso te ajudar com sua dúvida.

Só rodar essa *query*:

```
SELECT
    `fn`.`nome` AS `funcionario`,
    `cf`.`nome` AS `chefe`
FROM `funcionario` AS `fn`
INNER JOIN `funcionario` AS `cf`
ON `fn`.`chefeId` = `cf`.`id`;
```

O resultado é este:

```
+-------------+----------+
| funcionario | chefe    |
+-------------+----------+
| João        | Joaquim  |
| José        | Joaquim  |
| Josefina    | João     |
| Joaquim     | Jurandir |
| Jurandir    | Josefina |
+-------------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```